# Neo4j fails to start

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j

Neo4j 5.15
java 17.09
My neo4j (community server) was running on EC2 without an Issue. Last week we have a java update, but it was still fine afterward. Today when I imported a small data, all went well and when I tried to import the full data which is around 1.5G my process broke and neo4j became un-available. I removed it, reinstalled the same version and the recent version. Nothing is working. Any idea what is happening?
error:

````
JIT compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
VM Arguments: [-Xmx128m, -Dapp.name=neo4j, -Dapp.pid=8597, -Dapp.repo=/usr/share/neo4j/repo, -Dapp.home=/usr/share/neo4j, -Dbasedir=/usr/share/neo4j]
Configuration files used (ordered by priority):
/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf
--------------------
org.neo4j.cli.CommandFailedException: Neo4j is not running.
    at org.neo4j.server.startup.Bootloader$Dbms.status(Bootloader.java:529)
    at org.neo4j.server.startup.StatusCommand.execute(StatusCommand.java:37)
    at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:37)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
    at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jAdminCommand.call(Neo4jAdminCommand.java:123)
    at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jAdminCommand.call(Neo4jAdminCommand.java:42)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
    at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jCommand.main(Neo4jCommand.java:41)
    at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jBoot.main(Neo4jBoot.java:30)```
````

Comment: You may not have removed all the old neo4j data. Try using a new EC2 instance.

Comment: Actually removing all the neo4j folders and paths + reboot the server solved it

Comment: OK, I added an answer to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you delete all the existing neo4j data before reinstalling. Or, just use a new ECS instance.